# How to show https and www in URL?

Tags: url, url-rewrite, https

I have a site i.e. [nutriment.com](http://nutriment.com), I want to show https and www both in the URL but the problem is that https is appearing but www not appearing the URL and https show only on the Home Page, not in the inner pages. I want to show https and www both in the URL of the site. You can check the problem on my site also my site is nutrient.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Goto `system->configuration->Web->Unsecure` and add `www` in the Base Url from Magento admin. ie(http://www.example.com/)
2. Goto `system->configuration->Web->Secure` and add `www` in the Base Url from Magento admin. ie(https://www.example.com/)

Comment: to make https for all pages, you will have to rewrite certain functionality of core module. Please ask it as a seperate question. Moreover, i will not recommend doing so as https connection is required only where the personal informations are transmitted. Doing it for all pages will decrease your site speed